# PSSession error: The maximum number of concurrent shells for this user has been exceeded

Tags: session, powershell, powershell-remoting, powershell-4.0

I started a few PSSessions through the `New-PSsession` cmdlet

These sessions were not closed, when I tried to open another session I got the following error message:

```
New-PSsession : Connecting to remote server serverName failed with the following error message : The WS-Management service cannot process the request. 
The maximum number of concurrent shells for this user has been exceeded. 
Close existing shells or raise the quota for this user. 
For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

When I try to get the open PSSessions on the same machine through the `Get-PSSession` cmdlet, nothing shows up.

I've logged out of the server I'm running my scripts on, restarted it, tried to find `powershell.exe` processes on the source and target server and tried all kinds of combinations of the PSSession cmdlets to remove the open sessions but can't find any trace of the open sessions that are blocking me from creating a new one.

Can anyone see what I'm missing here?

*Powershell v4 on Server 2008 R2 source machine and Server 2012 target machine*

Comment: Are you just connecting to the 2008 box or is there something like exchange running on it that your connecting to?

Comment: Just connecting to the 2008 box

Comment: This problem appears to have resolved itself over the weekend, I can make remote sessions and remove them without issue but can't figure out why this problem happened in the first place